# Horizontal lookup with sorted in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have created this pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'Char1': [-3,2,0], 'Char2': [0,1,2], 'Char3': [-1,0,-1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I need to create two additional fields:

- Factor1
- Factor2

This is how Factor1 and Factor2 should be populated across each record:

- Factor1 should contain the name of the column with lowest value (again, across each record);
- Factor2 should contain the name of the column with the second lowest value (again, across each record).

So, the resulting dataset should look like this:

[image]

So, let's take a look at the first record:

- what is the lowest value? It's -3
- what is the name of the column that that -3 correspond to? It's Char1 -> "Char1" is then assigned to Factor1
- what is the second lowest value? It's -1
- what is the name of the column that that -1 correspond to? It's Char3 -> "Char3" is then assigned to Factor2

And so on.

How can I do this in Python/Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient method is to use the underlying numpy array with [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```py
import numpy as np

df[['Factor1', 'Factor2']] = df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(df.to_numpy())[:, :2]]
```

output:

```
   Char1  Char2  Char3 Factor1 Factor2
0     -3      0     -1   Char1   Char3
1      2      1      0   Char3   Char2
2      0      2     -1   Char3   Char1
```

###### generalization to N columns:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 2

order = np.argsort(df.to_numpy())[:, :N]
df[[f'Factor{i+1}' for i in range(N)]] = df.columns.to_numpy()[order]
```

example for `N=3`:

```
   Char1  Char2  Char3 Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
0     -3      0     -1   Char1   Char3   Char2
1      2      1      0   Char3   Char2   Char1
2      0      2     -1   Char3   Char1   Char2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `idxmin` and in order to get 2nd small we can `mask` the `min`

```
out = df.assign( **{'factor1' : df.idxmin(1), 
                    'factor2' : df.mask(df.eq(df.min(1),axis=0)).idxmin(1)})
Out[28]: 
   Char1  Char2  Char3 factor1 factor2
0     -3      0     -1   Char1   Char3
1      2      1      0   Char3   Char2
2      0      2     -1   Char3   Char1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the min across columns by

```
df['Factor1'] = df.idxmin(axis="columns")
```

then, you can either add the minimum in each column to get again the minimum or apply a mask to remove the already taken value